# Accessing columns of manually declared aliased tables in JOOQ

Tags: java, sql, jooq

I am manually declaring tables and fields for simple (but type safe) queries in JOOQ using:

```
Table<Record> myTable = DSL.table(DSL.name("my_table"));
Field<String> myField = DSL.field(DSL.name("my_table", "my_field"), String.class);
```

Creating an alias for `myTable` is easy:

```
Table<Record> myAlias = myTable.as("a");
```

But how can I access the value of `myField` within `myAlias`?

*Note that `myAlias.field(myField)` will yield `null`, as the field is not part of this table definition.*

Answer (score 6):

You cannot access fields from plain SQL tables, as jOOQ doesn't know anything about them. You'll have to construct individual field references for each alias, e.g.

```
Field<?> myAliasedField = field(name("a", "my_field"), String.class);
```

Comment: Isn't there any possibility to programmatically create a "column-aware" table that would allow for the `myAlias.field(myField)` construct? (This would create a nice middle ground between generated schema and plain SQL in JOOQ.)

Comment: @Timo: Yes, sure. You can implement `TableImpl`. Just like the code generator does for you. But then, why not just use the code generator? :) Another option is to use `org.jooq.Meta` (from `DSLContext.meta()`) to discover catalogs / schemas / tables / columns at runtime.

Comment: Using `TableImpl` would be great, except for all the `createField()` methods being *protected*. The resulting code then starts to resemble the output of the generator. :-(

Comment: So, what's your problem with the code generator, then?

Comment: Thanks. I couldnt get my head around why I was able to perform select on the DSL.table but not get the field. That explains it!